# Parsing a table in XML file with jquery

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing

I've to parse an xml file that has a part like that:

```
<part>configuration</part>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Tester Name</th>
      <th>Campaign Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>john</td>
      <td>random</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The thing is i have to parse another `<table>` too, that is in the same file with another `<part>` name.
I have searched a lot but i couldn't find a function or a way to retrieve for instance the tester name and the campaign name.
I am a beginner in jquery that is probably why i didn't find/understand how to parse these datas.
Thanks for everyone that would help me !
whether it be links to tutorials or functions suggestions.

Comment: What is parent for each `<part><table>` combination?

Comment: The parent seems to be <document> but <part> is closed before <table> (like <part>...</part> and then <table>...</table>).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [jQuery.parseXML()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) to parse a string into an XML document.

Then you need [Next Adjacent Selector (“prev + next”)](https://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-selector/) in order to select the table next to the part element. In order to select the part element with a specified text you need to use [:contains() Selector](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

The snippet:

```js
var xml = `<start>
              <part>configuration</part>
               <table>
                  <thead>
                     <tr>
                        <th>Tester Name</th>
                        <th>Campaign Name</th>
                    </tr>
                 </thead>
                 <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td>john</td>
                      <td>random</td>
                    </tr>
                 </tbody>
              </table>
          </start>`;
          
          
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml );  // parse xml string
var xml = $( xmlDoc );    // get the jQuery object
// find the table next to part tag containing.....
var tbl = $xml.find( "part:contains(configuration) + table" );

console.log(tbl.get(0).outerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! That already helps but i would to know if it's possible to get the value of Tester name and Campaign name in some var (such as var tester_name=...).

Comment: First: xml.find( "part:contains(configuration) + table th:first").text(); and xml.find( "part:contains(configuration) + table th:eq(1)").text(); for second value

Comment: ah super! I couldn't find anything about the th:first/eq. Thank you very much!